# How to set document body to a div by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want my page only to show the content of a div, and discard all other elements, so I try to set my body to that div, but it just failed:

My code:

```js
document.body = document.querySelector('#b')
```

```html
<div id="a">
    div a
</div>

<div id="b">
    div b
</div>
```

And result:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to set the 'body' property on 'Document': The new body element is of type 'DIV'. It must be either a 'BODY' or 'FRAMESET' element.",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 23
}
```

So, How to set document body to a div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the Error, you cannot set the `div` or other element to the body.

You can change the HTML inside `body` element.

Set the `innerHTML` of body to the `outerHTML` of the target element. This will replace the previous content of body by the new content.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#b').outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="a">
  div a
</div>

<div id="b">
  div b
</div>
```

Comment: You got me by just 11 seconds :P :)

Comment: I found the event listener which bind to that div went away. Is there any way to work around with that?

Comment: @Sayakiss In this case, you can bind event on `body` itself or bind the event after replacing the content of `body` by `div`.

Comment: @Sayakiss See [add event listener on elements created dynamically](//stackoverflow.com/q/14258787)

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="a">
    div a
</div>

<div id="b">
    div b
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
document.body = document.querySelector('#b')
```

With

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML
```

Comment: I found the event listener which bind to that div went away. Is there any way to work around with that?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery:  $('div').not(':first').remove();